# Scrapy simulate XHR request - returning 400

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get data from a site using Ajax. The page loads and then Javascript requests the content. See this page for details: https://www.tele2.no/mobiltelefon.aspx

The problem is that when i try to simulate this process by calling this url:
https://www.tele2.no/Services/Webshop/FilterService.svc/ApplyPhoneFilters

I get a 400 response telling me that the request is not allowed.
This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json

class Tele2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tele2"
    #allowed_domains = ["tele2.no/mobiltelefon.aspx"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.tele2.no/mobiltelefon.aspx/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://www.tele2.no/Services/Webshop/FilterService.svc/ApplyPhoneFilters'
        my_data = "{filters: []}"
        req = scrapy.Request( url, method='POST', body=json.dumps(my_data), headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest','Content-Type':'application/json'}, callback=self.parser2)
        yield req

    def parser2(self, response):
      print "test"
```

I'm new to scrapy and python so there might be something obvious I'm missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem is in missing quotes around the `filters` in the body:

```
url = 'https://www.tele2.no/Services/Webshop/FilterService.svc/ApplyPhoneFilters'
req = scrapy.Request(url,
                     method='POST',
                     body='{"filters": []}',
                     headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
                     callback=self.parser2)
yield req
```

Or, you can define it as a dictionary and then call `json.dumps()` to dump it to a string:

```
params = {"filters": []}
req = scrapy.Request(url,
                     method='POST',
                     body=json.dumps(params),
                     headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
                     callback=self.parser2)
```

As a proof, here is what it is giving me on the console:

```
2014-12-30 12:30:38-0500 [tele2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tele2.no/mobiltelefon.aspx/> (referer: None) 
2014-12-30 12:30:42-0500 [tele2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.tele2.no/Services/Webshop/FilterService.svc/ApplyPhoneFilters> (referer: https://www.tele2.no/mobiltelefon.aspx/) 
test
```

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm yes, initially you've called `json.dumps()` on a string - this is where the issue was. Glad it is solved now. Thanks.

Comment: I have just one more question, It seems like I'm getting an XML response to this request. However the website is returning a json response. Have i missed some setting?

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm yup, add `'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'` header.