# Scrapy/Python XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: python, scrapy, xmlhttprequest

I built a scraper that works up to a point: It navigates to a list of records, parses the records to key ones for further crawling, goes to those individual records but is unable to parse tables in the records because they are loaded via JavaScript. JavaScript issues a `POST` request (xmr) to populate them. So if JavaScript is not enabled it returns something like 'No records found.'

So I read this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709422/scrapy-simulate-xhr-request-returning-400)

I inspected Request Headers with browser dev tools. Headers include:

```
fetch("https://example.com/Search/GridQuery?query=foo", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
  },
  "referrer": "https://example.com/SiteSearch/Search?query=bar",
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body": "page=1&size=10&useFilters=false",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

The browser does indicate a cookie although not output by copying fetch...
I then tried this:

```
url = response.urljoin(response.css('div#Foo a::attr(href)').get())
yield Request(url=url,
              method='POST',
              body='{"filters": ["page": "1", "size": "10", "useFilters": "False"]}',
              headers={'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
              callback=self.parse_table)
```

I get a response but it still says 'No records found'. So the `POST` request is not working right.

Do I need to put everything in the request header? How do I determine what must be included? Are cookies required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test this, since you didn't provide real url, but I see a couple of problems there.
Note that content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and you are sending JSON object in the body (that's for `application/json`)

Instead, you should be sending [FormRequest](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects):

```
url = "https://example.com/Search/GridQuery?query=foo"
form_data = {"page": "1", "size": "10", "useFilters": "False"}
yield FormRequest(url, formdata=form_data, callback=self.parse_table)
```

Or simply add parameters as query parameters in the URL (still POST request, just omit the body).

```
url="https://example.com/Search/GridQuery?query=foo&page=1&size=10&useFilters=False"
```

Either way, you do not need that `"filters":[]`, just use simple key-value object.

Comment: I revised headers to be equal to everything returned by fetch. Then I set body equal to the string returned by fetch.
`yield Request(url=url,
                      method='POST',
                      body="page=1&size=10&useAnyMatchWithFilters=false",
                      headers=headers,
                      callback=self.parse_table)`
Now it returns a text file (the request was for "text/plain" with what is presumably a JSON object. I suspect this is parsed by the script objects in the HTML to make a table. Need to figure out how to scrapy .txt with JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but if you get a valid JSON object, you can load it using `json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())`. It may fail if text contains `'` instead of `"`, so in that case put  `json.loads(response.body_as_unicode().replace("'", '"'))`.

Comment: Wow. You saved me days of research. Thanks.